# Can i store a list of types to intantiate?

Tags: java

I would like to have a class that can create instances of other classes, by index. I want a list containing all the types (all of which extend `Object`) that can be instantiated, so I can have a function like `public Object newObject(int i)` which will return a new instance of that type (they each have a default constructor).

Is there a way for me to store a list of types?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-factory-pattern

Comment: Please add what you have tired.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174359/create-different-objects-depending-on-type

Comment: That's... interesting. Sure, classes are a thing, same way you'd create a JDBC driver using reflection.

Comment: Sure? Just create a list of the Classes. instead of class instance? But _why_ do you think you need to do this? Because one of the powers of a strongly typed language is that you're _not_ guessing at what the code is doing. At the very least have them all use the same interface or extend from some superclass. If your code has to use `Object` as type in order for things to work, the proverbial "you're doing it wrong" almost certainly applies. As for "all of which extends `Obect`": yes, of course, that's how Java works. All classes extend Object, whether you write `extends Object` or not.

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. Can you explain the actual problem you are having? This seems like your solution to the problem you are having.

Comment: i should clarify, i have my own class called Object that is not the native Object class. it is confusing in retrospect. really it should be called "GameObject."

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options here.

- Factory pattern (recommended)
- Reflective access (don't go here)

Nevertheless the second option is quite common. I'm going to explain it first so you know what to avoid, and to put the factory solution in context.

### Reflective access

Classes have an object representation: An instance of the `java.lang.Class` class. You can get these instances trivially: `Class<?> c = String.class;` gets you the class object representing the string class. Not "A string" - that'd be `String x = "";` - nono, the concept of all strings as a type. You can also get them via `Class<?> c = Class.forName("java.lang.String");` as well.

Given such an object, you can fetch the no-args constructor and invoke it:

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
Constructor<?> noArgsConstructor = c.getConstructor();
Object fresh = noArgsConstructor.newInstance();
System.out.println("".equals(fresh)); // prints 'true'
```

However, there are a bunch of problems with this:

- The generics of `Class` (and `Constructor`) are broken. Generics allows generics - you can have a `List<List<String>>` (generics in your generics). However, there is only one class instance per class, in other words, `List<String>` and `List<Integer>`? That's the same class - hence, only one `Class` instance, hence **`Class` instances cannot themselves have generics**. On the flipside, generics can't deal with primitives (`List<int>` is not (yet) a thing in java), but `int.class` works fine and gets you a `Class` instance representing primitive ints. So, it's a broken abstraction and this results in all sorts of issues. Specifically, imagine a method that takes in a `Class<?>` instance; your method will make a new object and then invoke something on it:

```
interface Namable {
  void setName(String name);
}

public static <T extends Namable> T create(Class<T> type) {
  T namable = type.newConstructor().newInstance();
  namable.setName("Jane");
  return namable;
}

// to use:

@lombok.Data
class Person implements Namable {
  String name;
}

Person p = create(Person.class);
System.out.println(p.name); // prints 'Jane'
```

So far, so good. But now let's do the same thing but using `List` instead of `Namable`:

```
public <L extends List<String>> L create(Class<L> listType) {
  List<String> list = listType.getConstructor().newInstance();
  list.add("Hello, World!");
  return list;
}
```

This.. compiles fine but you can't use it without lots of problems and compiler warnings:

```
create(ArrayList<String>.class); // does not compile
create(ArrayList.class); // does, but warnings.
```

- This reflective access throws a ton of exceptions. You can handle them of course, but it's annoying.
- The compiler and type system won't help you here. As part of the 'contract', the `Class<T> type` parameter must be some type which has all sorts of requirements: It needs to be instantiable (cannot be an interface or abstract or an enum), and it needs to have a `public` constructor that takes zero arguments. Any exceptions it throws also end up wrapped because you can't put limits on which checked exceptions it can throw either. This is a worst of both worlds solution: Java is strongly and nominally typed but we ditch all that here and just decree what is required in the documentation, and if you feel to heed the docs, no compiler/write-time errors occur at all, it'll blow up with some sort of error at runtime. That's bad.

Hence, **this is not a good idea**.

### Factory pattern

The reason it's all so wonky is that **static members do not 'do' type hierarchy**. A constructor is simply a wonky static method - think about it: You cannot declare that some constructor is required in an interface - that's the same as static methods. They do not do dynamic dispatch either - just like static methods. They do not require a receiver (the `x` in `x.foo()` is called the receiver) - just like static methods.

You simply cannot make an interface that decrees that any type that `implements` that interface must have certain static properties. At all. java as a language fundamentally doesn't work that way. Only instances play the dynamic dispatch game and thus only for instances does it make sense to have a type hierarchy that lets you make promises (such as: "All things that are of type `List` have a `.size()` method regardless of which particular list it is), and thus, lets the tooling (compiler, editor) help.

So, we need to somehow turn static things into instance things.

Enter: **The factory pattern**.

A factory is simply a second meta-layer describing not so much 'a tree' as 'a thing that knows about a certain genus of trees and can make new trees':

```
public interface Tree {
  void sprout();
}

class Birch implements Tree {
  public void sprout() { ... }
}
```

we add to this:

```
public interface TreeFactory {
  Tree create();
}

public class BirchFactory implements TreeFactory {
  Birch create() { return new Birch(); }
}
```

We have now 'instance-ified' what used to be a static aspect - as per the notion of 'tree' or 'birch', `create()` is "static" - as a concept it applies to all of them. But from the notion of a 'tree maker', `create()` is an instance thing - each tree maker has its own create concept.

With this pattern, all problems that reflective access have go away:

- You can use the interface to decree that you have e.g. no arguments.
- No weird checked exceptions to deal with.
- Works just fine with generics.

### Implicit factories

One variant of factories is the implicit factory - instead of explicitly making a `TreeFactory` object, you can also just pass along a function that makes them on the fly. In fact, java core library's own `Collectors.toMap` and `Collection.toArray` employ this technique: Due to generics a collection cannot actually create a new array of the right type so it needs you to tell it how to do that. You can do this with a `IntFunction<E[]>` - a function that takes in an `int` and emits an `E[]` where `E` is the type of the collection component:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.toArray(size -> new String[size]);
// or simpler:
list.toArray(String[]::new);
```

and you can apply the same techique to your code:

```
public <T extends Tree> List<T> plantManyTrees(int size, Supplier<? extends T> treeFactory) {
  var planted = new ArrayList<T>();
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    planted.add(treeFactory.get());
  }
  return planted;
}

// to use:

List<Birch> copseOfBirches = plantManyTrees(100, () -> new Birch());
```

or even, if you want, say, a dynamic string-based lookup for tree types:

```
Map<String, Supplier<? extends Tree>> makers = new HashMap<>();

makers.put("Birch", () -> new Birch());
makers.put("Willow", () -> new Willow());
```

and so on

Comment: @rzwitsetloot, Your response is incredibly verbose, although very helpful.  In my opinion, you should just offer the "Factory Pattern" solution, the first recommendation includes some invalid statements.  Generics are not "broken", and of course `List<int>` is possible.  `Collections` were built specifically with `Object`s in mind, and that's why there are various nuances when attempting to use primitive data-types.

Comment: @Reilas Generics __on `java.lang.Class`__ is broken. You're putting words in my mouth. `List<int>` is not possible (try it). You see why a lengthy response is necessary; this stuff is complicated - complicated enough to confuse you, evidently.

Comment: Interesting, I thought it would autobox.  And, yeah, I guess, I just think saying that it's broken is incorrect.

Comment: nit about the reflection approach: we really don't need to unpack each step with explicit imports, `MyClass x = (MyClass) Class.forName("MyClass").getConstructor().newInstance();` is so much nicer than spreading it out over multiple lines of "I don't actually care about the intermediaries and have no reason to capture them" =)

Comment: @Reilas I gave you 2 objective reasons why the generics param specifically of `java.lang.Class` is broken, which isn't an official term, but in context pretty clear means: Extremely leaky and doesn't properly represent what it is trying to represent. Specifically: There are `Class` instances of the primitive types which the generics cannot represent, and generics can represent things with generics in them, but `Class` instances cannot represent those. If you think about it in terms of venn diagrams, it's 2 circles that mostly overlap but each circle has a small area that does not(the classic).

Comment: @Mike I intentionally wrote it out in 3 separate lines. snippets in Stack Overflow do not enjoy the benefits of an IDE (you cannot mouse over the `getConstructor()` part and from there realize this returns a `java.lang.reflect.Constructor`.

Comment: i think that the factory pattern is functionally what i was doing originally, but it seemed overly complicated to have to make a new factory class for each object class. i want to be able to scale this for a project with many kinds of objects, so it's much easier if each object subclass can contain it's own interpretations and i can just instantiate them by index in some registry of types. reflective access seems more like what i was looking for, but if that pattern is really a problem in the long term then i guess i'll try something like an implicit factory. thanks!