# Android java unable to load class

Tags: java, android, loader, dex

hi am unable to load class in my android app , i can load basic class but when i Initialize context in that class then am not able to load it

```
public class main {
    // Initalize context
    Context mContext;
    public main(Context mContext){
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }
    public boolean main() {
 Log.d("MYLOG", "main() called successfully when there context is not initialized like above");
// some code here  
}
}
```

my class loading code

```
try{
     final File tmpDir = context.getDir("dex", 0);
     final DexClassLoader classloader = new DexClassLoader(libPath, tmpDir.getAbsolutePath(), null, this.getClass().getClassLoader());
     final Class<Object> classToLoad = (Class<Object>) classloader.loadClass("com.myproject.test.dumy_class");   // package plus main class
     final Object myInstance = classToLoad.newInstance();       // throwing exception here 
}
    } catch (Exception e) {
// exception thrown at that statement :   final Object myInstance = classToLoad.newInstance(); 
}
```

Exception i got :

> java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class
>   com.myproject.test.dumy_class; no empty constructor

so please help .

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Add whole stactrace please!

Comment: @MartinKonecny i have edited code , i enclosed the code with try{}  and so problem occur when it reach to  that satement :  final Object myInstance = classToLoad.newInstance();

Comment: @MartinKonecny  Exception : java.lang.InstantiationException: can't instantiate class com.myproject.test.dumy_class; no empty constructor

Comment: You need to either add a default (empty) constructor, or choose which constructor you want. I've posted detailed response in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an empty contructor in your Java class:

```
public class main {
    // Initalize context
    Context mContext;

    public main(){
    }

    public main(Context mContext){
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }
    public boolean main() {
       Log.d("MYLOG", "main() called successfully when there context is not initialized like above");
        // some code here  
    }
}
```

This will only call the empty constructor, which may not be what you want.

Alternatively, you need to choose the constructor you want and add a parameter to your newInstance call (see [related SO question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234600/can-i-use-class-newinstance-with-constructor-arguments)) like so:

```
Class[] cArg = new Class[1];
cArg[0] = Context.class;
classToLoad.getDeclaredConstructor(cArg).newInstance(context);
```

so your non-empty constructor

```
public main(Context mContext)
```

is called.