# Android java.lang.NullPointerException due to ContentResolver()

Tags: java, android, exception, null

I am trying to load classes dynamically with `DexClassLoader`

I loaded `main()` method in main class

> my main class with main() method

```
public class main {
    // Initalize context
    Context mContext;
    public main(){
    }
    public main(Context mContext){
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }
    public boolean main() {
        p2_contacts contact_obj = new p2_contacts(mContext);
        if (contact_obj.Fetch_Load_Contacts()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }   // main function ends

}  // main class end point
```

> contacts class

```
public class p2_contacts {
// Initalize context
    Context mContext;
    public p2_contacts(Context mContext){
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }
    public boolean Fetch_Load_Contacts() {
        try{
        Uri CONTENT_URI = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        ContentResolver contentResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();     //  exception throwing : 06-09 18:23:05.658: W/System.err(22026): java.lang.NullPointerException

        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(CONTENT_URI, null,null, null, null);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
```

so please help, how to overcome this problem ?

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = mContext.getContentResolver();     //  exception throwing : 06-09 18:23:05.658: W/System.err(22026): java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: From where do you pass context to main constructor

Comment: @Raghunandan  i have poor knowledage about android context , i Initalize context separately in both classes

Comment: where do you call the `new main(context)`. post that code. `mContext` is likely null

Comment: @Raghunandan  am loading this main class through DexLoader , you can see my previous post      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24108492/android-java-unable-to-load-class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must be calling `public main(){}` followed by `public boolean main() {...}`, which means that you are not assigning a value to the context in `main`.

Alternatively, you may be calling `public main(Context mContext){...}` followed by `public boolean main() {...}`, but passing null as the context.

Comment: so how can i get context for the separate class public class main  or public class p2_contacts    because i can't pass context from my activity to them because am loading class public main with dex loader as it's separate android library project .

Comment: for example :  final Class<Object> classToLoad = (Class<Object>) classloader.loadClass(pack);   // package plus main class name       // so how can i pass context with .loadclass(pack) !!!!      or any separate way to declare context for that external library which am loading