# Java calling method from generic class

Tags: java, list, generics, methods, reflection

Is something like that possible.

```
List<?> myList = getMyList();
class cls = class.forname("com.lab.myClass");
cls = myList.get(0);
cls.getValue();
```

Create an Instance with the fully-qualified name of a class and use their declared Methods?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234600/can-i-use-class-newinstance-with-constructor-arguments)?

Comment: If you have the fully qualified name, you know what type it is. If you know what type it is, just use it directly.

Comment: did you follow some tutorials about java reflection? you should, it will save you frustration in the future (and now).

Answer (score 1):

No, if you call `Class.forName`, at compile time you know nothing about the returned `Class` instance. You don't even know that it represents a class; it might be an interface for example. In particular, if it is a class and you create an instance of it, you cannot call any methods of it except those which are already defined in `Object` because, at compile time, the compiler cannot check whether these methods exist.

The are two solutions:

First, you can use reflection to find out about the methods the class has, and to call these methods. This is very cumbersome.

Second, if you use `Class.forName` to dynamically load classes at runtime, often you know something about the classes you load. For example, you might know that the class implements a certain interface. Then you can cast the result of `newInstance` to this interface and then call the methods defined in this interface directly.

For example:

```
// in file Plugin.java
interface Plugin {
    void doSomething();
}

// in file Main.java
public class Main { 
    ...
    void runPlugin() {
        try {
            Class<?> pluginClass = Class.forName("pkg.name.MyPlugin");
            Plugin plugin = (Plugin) pluginClass.newInstance();
            plugin.doSomething();
        }
        catch (...) {
            // catch the necessary exceptions
        }
    }
}
```