# Use the command line to make new objects

Tags: java

In my program, the user needs to input what type of players the game will have. The players are `"human"`, `"good"` (for a good AI), `"bad"` (for a bad AI) and `"random"` (for a random AI). Each of these players have their own class that extend one abstract class called `PlayerType`.

My struggle is mapping a `String` to the object so I can A) create a new object using the String as sort of a key and B) get the related `String` from an object of its subclass

Ultimately, I just want the implicit `String` to only appear once in the code so I can change it later if needed without refactoring.

I've tried using just a plain HashMap, but that seems clunky with searching the keys via the values. Also, I'm guessing that I'll have to use the `getInstance()` method of `Class`, which is a little less clunky, which is okay if it's the only way.

Comment: Register your classes with a factory using the classes' string key as the key, and the class itself as the value.

Comment: Is this continual input or just when it's launched?

Comment: probably some sort of switch statement based on the names available, and then just return a new instance of whichever matches.

Comment: @CasualT Can't do that because OP wants to use strings contained within the classes themselves as the keys.

Comment: well, you can still reference those classes in a switch...
otherwise, would need to use reflection to scan dynamically.

Comment: @CasualT, that's not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is create an `enum` which essentially functions as a factory for the given type.

```
public enum PlayerTypes {
    GOOD { 
        @Override
        protected PlayerType newPlayer() { 
            return new GoodPlayer();
        }
    }, 
    BAD {
        @Override
        protected PlayerType newPlayer() { 
            return new BadPlayer();
        }
    },
    RANDOM {
        @Override
        protected PlayerType newPlayer() { 
            return new RandomPlayer();
        }
    };

    protected abstract PlayerType newPlayer();

    public static PlayerType create(String input) {
        for(PlayerTypes player : PlayerTypes.values()) {
             if(player.name().equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {
                 return player.newPlayer();
             }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid player type [" + input + "]");
    }
)
```

Because then you can just call it like so:

```
String input = getInput();
PlayerTypes.create(input);
```

Of course, you'll get an `IllegalArgumentException` which you should probably handle by trying to get the input again.

EDIT: Apparently in this particular case, you can replace that loop with just merely

```
return PlayerTypes.valueOf(input).newPlayer();
```

And it'll do the same thing. I tend to match for additional constructor parameters in the `enum`, so I didn't think of using `valueOf()`, but it's definitely cleaner.

EDIT2: Only way to get that information back is to define an abstract method in your `PlayerType` class that returns the `PlayerTypes` enum for that given type.

```
public class PlayerType {
    public abstract PlayerTypes getType();
}

public class GoodPlayer extends PlayerType {
    @Override
    public PlayerTypes getType() {
        return PlayerTypes.GOOD;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are willing to picky about upper/lower-casing, you just `return PlayerTypes.valueOf(input).newPlayer();`. You'll get the IllegalArgumentException for free since that's the exception that `valueOf()` throws if it can't match up the type.

Comment: @azurefrog valid point, I edited it in now that I'm not on a pesky phone soft keyboard, thanks for the info

Comment: This answers my problem to A). Could it be possible to have an instance of, say, a `GoodPlayer` and then grab name it's tied to? (for my problem B) I guess the enum has to be bidirectional

Comment: Answered that too now.

Answer (score 1):

I like the answer provided by Epic but I don't find maps to be clunky. So it's possible to keep a map and get the constructor call directly.

```
Map<String, Supplier<PlayerType> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("human", Human::new);
Human h = map.get("human").get();
```

Comment: Would this be possible to do with a non default constructors?

Comment: No, you'd have to use a slightly different interface that allows for parameters depending on how many you have. Or provide an init method to call on the instance. @Kyefer

Answer (score 0):

The two main options I can think of:

Using `Class.newInstance()`, as you mentioned (not sure if you had this exact way in mind):

```
// Set up your map
Map<String, Class> classes = new HashMap<String, Class>();
classes.put("int", Integer.class);
classes.put("string", String.class);

// Get your data
Object s = classes.get("string").newInstance();
```

You could use `Class.getDeclaredConstructor.newInstance` if you want to use a constructor with arguments ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234600/can-i-use-class-newinstance-with-constructor-arguments)).

---

Another option is using `switch`:

```
Object getObject(String identifier) {
    switch (identifier) {
        case "string": return new String();
        case "int": return new Integer(4);
    }
    return null; // or throw an exception or return a default object
}
```

Comment: The `::new` (from Java 8) as suggested in [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32614878/1711796) is perhaps better than my first option.

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution:

```
public class ForFunFactory {

    private ForFunFactory() {
    }

    public static AThing getTheAppropriateThing(final String thingIdentifier) {
        switch (thingIdentifier) {
            case ThingImplApple.id:
                return new ThingImplApple();
            case ThingImplBanana.id:
                return new ThingImplBanana();
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("AThing with identifier "
                        + thingIdentifier + " not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public interface AThing {
    void doStuff();
}
```

---

```
class ThingImplApple implements AThing {

    static final String id = "Apple";

    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("I'm an Apple.");
    }

}
```

---

```
class ThingImplBanana implements AThing {

    static final String id = "Banana";

    @Override
    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("I'm a Banana.");
    }

}
```