# Is it possible to create an instance of parameterized class in Java?

Tags: java, reflection, parameterization

I have the same logic in classes creation, but actual classes are different. Is it possible somehow to create an instance of a parameterized class?

Here is an example:

```
public class MyClass <E extends MyEntityClass> {
    public List<E> myList = new LinkedList<>();

    public MyClass(JsonArray params) {
        for(JsonElement param : params){
            myList.add(new E(param));
        }
    }
}
```

MyEntityClass - is the super class which has the constructor which accepts JsonElement.

I know that Java doesn't allow to create the parameterized class, but is it possible to solve somehow this problem?

Comment: You could try to combine [Get generic type of class at runtime

](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime) wuth [Can I use Class.newInstance() with constructor arguments?

](http://https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234600/can-i-use-class-newinstance-with-constructor-arguments)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create instance of generic type in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75175/create-instance-of-generic-type-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics are erased after compilation.
So of course, instantiating directly a parameterized type as you try to do is not possible.

As workaround, you could pass a factory method to your constructor.

With functional interface, you could add a parameter `Function<JsonElement,E>` in your constructor and use it to create instances of the generic element :

```
public class MyClass<E extends MyEntityClass> {
    public List<E> myList = new LinkedList<>();

    public MyClass(JsonArray params, Function<JsonElement, E> factoryE) {
        for(JsonElement param : params){
            myList.add(factoryE.apply(param));
        }
    }
}
```

And you could instantiate your class in this way :

```
MyClass<MyEntityClass> myClass = new MyClass<MyEntityClass>(MyEntityClass::new);
```

With a `MyEntityClass` defined with a constructor that accepts a `JsonElement` parameter :

```
public class MyEntityClass {
    ...
    public MyEntityClass(JsonElement jsonElement){
      ...
    }
   ...
}
```

Of course, you can achieve the same thing without functional interface but it would be more verbose.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering!