# Instantiate Object with constructor arguments in a generic method

Tags: java, generics, constructor, instance

I am currently attempting to write a method which returns a new array of a generic type filled with objects of random values but I am struggling with the creation of the Objects.

Let's say I have a class **Rectangle** and a class **Cricle** which both can only be initialised by their constructor and lack an empty constructor. Is it possible to access the constructor of those example classes when working with a generic method?

**Rectangle.java**

```
public class Rectangle
{
  private double width;
  private double height;
  private double area;

  public Rectangle( double width, double height )
  {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.area = width * height;
  }
  // Getter....
}
```

**Circle.java**

```
public class Circle
{
  private double area;
  private double radius;

  public Circle( double radius )
  {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.area = Math.PI * Math.pow( radius, 2 );
  }
  // Getter....
}
```

What I hoped could work out somehow:

**ArrayFactory.java**

```
public class ArrayFactory<T>
{

  @SuppressWarnings ( "unchecked")
  public T[] getArray( int size, int min, int max )
  {
    Random ran = new Random();
    double var1 = (ran.nextDouble() * max) - min;
    double var2 = (ran.nextDouble() * max) - min;

    T[] temp = (T[]) new Object[size];

    for ( int i = 0; i < t.length; i++ )
    {
      // this does obviously not work 
      // because the constructor of java.lang.Object takes no arguments
      temp[ i ] = (T) new Object(var1,var2);
    }
    return temp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use a factory class

Comment: @MauricePerry But how would I decide which Factory to use? It would depend on the type `T`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Yes it would...

Comment: `T` exists only at compilation time. At runtime it is erased to `Object`. If you want to preserve information about `T` at runtime you may need to have additional argument of type `Class<T>`. For instance it is used in reflection via `Arrays.newInstance(String.class, 5)` which creates `new String[5]` instead of `new Object[5]`. Such class literal can be used to access available constructors (read more at [Can I use Class.newInstance() with constructor arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/234600))

Comment: @Pshemo thank you for the quick explanation. I knew about `Class.getConstructor(...).newInstance(...)` but I thought/hoped that I could somehow retriev this information from the generic. But as you pointed out the information gets erased.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hopeless because neither `Rectangle` nor `Circle` share a common base class or interface.  Generics cannot help you here.

This looks like inheritance 101 `Shape` example.  (`Animal` is the other common one.)

You can do this:

```
public interface Shape {
    double area();
    double perimeter();
}

public class Rectangle implements Shape {
    private double width;
    private double height;

    public Rectangle(double w, double h) {
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
    }

    public double area() { return w*h; }
    public double perimeter() { return 2.0*(w+h); }
}

public class ShapeFactory() { 
    public Shape createShape(double ... args) {
        if (args.length == 1) {
            return new Circle(args[0]);
        } else if (args.length == 2) { 
            return new Rectangle(args[0], args[1]);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong number of arguments");
        }
    }
}
```

This factory will "work", but it's limited.  You can't distinguish between Shapes that have two ctor arguments (e.g. `Rectangle`, `Square`, `Triangle`, `Rhombus`, 3D cylinder, etc.)  For those you'll have to pass a `Class`, in addition to the variable number of dimension parameter values, and use `instanceOf`.

Using `instanceOf` is usually a dead giveaway that your use of polymorphism is broken, but I would say it's acceptable in this case, as long as it's isolated to the factory method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a factory class implementing:

```
public interface ArrayFactory<T> {
    public T newElement();
    public T[] newArray(int size);
}
```

example:

```
class RectangleArrayFactory implements ArrayFactory<Rectangle> {
    private final Random ran = new Random();
    private final int min;
    private final int max;

    public RectangleArrayFactory(int min, int max) {
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    @Override
    public Rectangle newElement() {
        double var1 = (ran.nextDouble() * max) - min;
        double var2 = (ran.nextDouble() * max) - min;
        return new Rectangle(var1, var2);
    }

    @Override
    public Rectangle[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Rectangle[size];
    }
}
```

To create and fill an array, you could do:

```
public <T> T[] newArray(ArrayFactory<T> fac, int size) {
    T[] result = fac.newArray(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        result[i] = fac.newElement();
    }
    return result;
}
```