# Java generics for class and new instance

Tags: java, generics

In Java, if I have:

```
public class Foo<T> {

  public Foo() { }

}
```

I can do `Foo<Integer> foo = new Foo<Integer>();` but I cannot find an equivalent syntax for using the `class` field, meaning that something like `Foo<Integer> foo = Foo<Integer>.class.newInstance();` doesn't work.  Is there a way to use generics via the newInstance method?

Comment: Why do you need this specifically ?

Comment: There is no way to get the class of a generic. Look in all examples they always do somthing like Foo<Integer> foo = new Foo<Integer>(Integer.class)

Comment: `Foo<Integer>.class` has no sense in Java due to type erasure: you only have the `Foo` type.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it only without parameterized type. `Class.newInstance()` is not quite recommendable. You can do this:

```
//Class<Foo<Integer>> clazz = Foo<Integer>.class; <-- Error
Class<Foo> clazz = Foo.class; // <-- Ok
Foo instance = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
```

[Why is Class.newInstance() evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195321/why-is-class-newinstance-evil)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

`.newInstance()` (and anything that uses `Class`) is a reflection API that fundamentally works at runtime. Therefore it has little to do with Generics which operates at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

`newInstance()` is an API from the early days of Java - no generics back then. You have to cast the return value.

Also: there will be no future method doing that, `newInstance()` is used to create objects dynamically at runtime. Due to type erasure in Java there is no generic information at runtime anymore.