# Replacing if else statements

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

I have a code which looks something like this:

```
if(num == 1) {
return new Alg1();
} else if (num == 2) {
return new Alg2();
}
...
else if (num == n) {
return new AlgN();
}
```

I have tried to use the Strategy pattern but it seems like it does not satisfy the task to reduce the if statements, can you please suggest me some other way to do it, thanks

Comment: use Switch ... case: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use reflection

```
try {
    return Class.forName("mypackage.Alg" + num).newInstance();
} catch (Exception e) { 
    // handle exception
}
```

You could chose to wrap with a RuntimeException or not wrap it if it was one you were expecting like

```
public static Algorythm loadAlgo(int n) throws IOException {
    try {
        return Class.forName("mypackage.Alg" + num).newInstance();

    } catch (Exception e) { 
        if (e instanceof IOException) 
            throw (IOException) e;
        throw new IOException("Unable to load Algo", e);
    }
```

You have to catch all exceptions not just checked ones with this `newInstance()` method as it doesn't wrap exceptions thrown in the constructor.  You could use the longer

```
try {
    return Class.forName("mypackage.Alg" + num).getConstructor().newInstance();
} catch (Exception e) { 
    // handle exception
}
```

However, it doesn't make much difference in this case except exception thrown will be wrapped and you might have to unwrap them to see the original.

Comment: Do not use Class.newInstance() use Class.getConstructor().newInstance() instead (Class.newInstance() does not have sane exception scheme). Typical overuse of reflection.

Comment: @k5_ I haven't mentioned how exception handling should work, I will add it to my answer.

Comment: You seriously think exception handling should look like that?

Comment: @k5_ I would happy for you to provide a complete alternative answer i.e. not one with a "..." I will let you fill in all the repetitive code here bit.

Comment: @k5_ I welcome a cleaner, simpler suggestion.

Comment: The problem with your first Class.newInstance() approach was that you would have swollowed everything that came from calling the constructor of AlgX(), almost no option to recover from that. My appraoch would be to catch InvocationTargetException and rethrow the targetexception leading to a "throws Throwable" sucks but at least something. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195321/why-is-class-newinstance-evil

Comment: @k5_ if you wanted to rethrow you could use a RuntimeException of your choice.

Comment: As Joshua Bloch said in his "Effective Java" - "prefer annotations to naming conventions", it will make your code more robust and clean.

Comment: @Andrei_N I agree if there is a standard annotation which all libraries recognise.  If you use an annotation only one library recognises, you are locking yourself into using that library.

Answer (score 6):

Unless you're going to provide 4 billion `Alg*` classes, use an `enum` instead of an `int`:

```
enum Strategy {
  ALG_1 { @Override public Alg1 newInstance() { return new Alg1(); },
  ALG_2 { @Override public Alg2 newInstance() { return new Alg2(); },
  // ...
  ;

  public abstract AlgBase newInstance();
}
```

Then there is no need for any conditionals:

```
return strategy.newInstance();
```

where `strategy` is the instance of `Strategy`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to dynamically add new algorithms you might want to take a look at spi. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html. These approaches mean that all algorithms must be initialisable, if one fails to construct none is usable.

With a textfile you register implementations of an interface and resolve these implementations by:

```
    ServiceLoader<Algorithm> algorithms = ServiceLoader.load(Algorithm.class);
    for (Algorithm algorithm : algorithms) {
        if (algorithm.getId().equals(num)) {
            return algorithm;
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Algorithm with num " + num + " does not exist");
```

That will return an Iterable for all implementations of that algorithm. You can loop through them to find the correct one.

You might want to store/cache the algorithms in a Map if you resolve them often in one run of your application.

This map can also be manually created if you dont want to use spi.

```
private static final Map<Integer, Algorithm> ALGORITHMS;

static {
    Map<Integer, Algorithm> algs = new HashMap<>();
    algs.put(1, new Alg1());
    algs.put(2, new Alg2());
    algs.put(3, new Alg3());
    ALGORITHMS = Collections.unmodifiableMap(algs);
}
```

Comment: A good suggestion.  Can you include how to handle exceptions if a service throws one? +1

Comment: So an Algo you don't need throws an exception on class initialisation. How would you handle that?

Comment: "You seriously think exception handling should look like that" - i.e. pretend they never happen I guess.

Comment: I added some errorhandling for the serviceloader. Fail fast, fail early isnt that bad of a strategy.

Comment: Will ServiceLoader catch and log an exception in an Algorithm you didn't ask for.

Comment: No it will throw an ServiceConfigurationError that is not handled here and will likely end the Thread that called the method containing the ServiceLoader.

Comment: Does this mean if an algo you don't need fails, you can't use the one you want?

Comment: Obviously. I added a comment to my original answer to clear that up.