# what is the advantage of using Class.forName() over the new keyword for loading an instance?

Tags: java, reflection

I know definition. we use `Class.forName("")` when we don't know the type of the class but that's the conundrum here.

If I say:

```
Class.forName("SomeClass");
```

So I know the type of "SomeClass". So all compiler does in  `Class.forName("SomeClass")` case is does not check whether "SomeClass" exists or not during the Compile time. But it will check it at run time. But is it really the advantage? Can anyone explain this to me with real time scenario?

Comment: What if you don't know at compile time which specific class you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Class.forName()` loads a class that doesn't need to be present at compile time - it just needs to be present when `Class.forName()` is executed (often class load time, could be runtime as well, depending on where the instruction is specified). This is often the case for, say, database-specific database drivers where implementation classes are provided by the application container and you don't need to care about the instance when developing your app.

An alternative, that would load the class at compile time, would be something like this:

```
import com.someclass.Foo;

Foo foo; // class would be loaded
```

However, this is still not an *instance* of a class that's created with `new` keyword. Instances are different - if you want an instance, you'd still create with `new`, irrelevant of how you actually load the *class*.

Answer (score 1):

`Class.forName()` gives you the *class* for the given name. It doesn't instantiate it. You *could* use `Class.newInstance()` for that (but there are issues with that - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195321/why-is-class-newinstance-evil) for more info)

Note that you'd use this in (say) a framework where a configuration file identifies the name of the class you want to load. i.e. that class could be changed at *runtime* (for example, a Spring XML configuration). In these situations, it's highly likely that your choice of classes would all implement a common interface - otherwise it's difficult for the subsequent code to interact with it.