# Java 9 replace Class.newInstance

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, java-9

[Class.newInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) was deprecated in Java 9:

> ```
> clazz.newInstance()
> ```
>
> can be replaced by
>
> ```
> clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()
> ```

The problem is that [getDeclaredConstructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) returns any constructor without regarding the access level.

If I want to replace all occurrences in my code (on different packages/access level) should I use [getConstructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-) to get the public constructor?

> the Constructor object of the public constructor that matches the specified parameterTypes

Or **can't** I *bulk* replace all occurrences because it needs to be per case (if a public constructor exists and/or if I have the right access level for the class)?

**EDIT**

getDeclaredConstructor:

> ```
>    return getConstructor0(parameterTypes, Member.DECLARED);
> ```

getConstructor:

> ```
>    return getConstructor0(parameterTypes, Member.PUBLIC);
> ```

Comment: If you need to access constructor at different levels, getDeclaredConstructor(s) is the only way out. Can't you use `getDeclaredConstructors​()` (not `getDeclaredConstructor()`) to get all constructors and replace one depending on your logic?

Comment: As the deprecation message says, the equivalent code to `clazz.newInstance()` is `clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()`. I would assume this means that anywhere you're successfully using `clazz.newInstance()` can be replaced with the recommended code. If you replace `clazz.newInstance()` with `clazz.getConstructor().newInstance()` you're changing the semantics of the code.

Comment: I haven’t tried, but I wouldn’t expect `clazz.newInstance()` to work either if the zero-arg constructor isn’t public — does it?? So what would you be losing in practice by using `clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()` instead?

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes, `Class.newInstance()` works with non-public constructors. But it requires you to have the proper access else it throws an `IllegalAccessException` (from some quick, non-exhaustive testing).

Comment: @Slaw Using `getDeclaredConstructor`, How can I be sure getting private constructor won't failed to create `newInstance`?

Comment: Related (on the reasons why it was deprecated): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195321/why-is-class-newinstance-evil

Answer (score 27, accepted):

These two calls invoke the same constructor, the zero-argument constructor:

1. `klass.newInstance()`
2. `klass.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()`

Both perform the same run-time check to verify the caller's access, if the constructor is not public. The only difference is that #2 wraps any checked exceptions instead of directly throwing. Otherwise they are identical and you can replace one with the other.

But this is different:

3. `klass.getConstructor().newInstance()`

because it can only return a public constructor. It throws a `NoSuchMethodException` if the constructor is not public.

So you can't change it to `getConstructor()` unless you know the constructor is public.

Comment: Thank you, so any exceptions thrown will only be  a valid initialization failures?

Comment: @user7294900 Yes.