# T::class.java.newInstance() deprecated

Tags: java, kotlin

```
inline fun <reified T> blah(block: T.() -> Unit): Something {
    request = T::class.java.newInstance()
```

that newInstance() is deprecated, usually when you go to the source, it says why it's deprecated and what the alternative is, but this time i'm only seeing:

```
/** @deprecated */
@CallerSensitive
@Deprecated(
    since = "9"
)
public T newInstance() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    // ...
}
```

What is the new non-deprecated way to create an instance of a reified type in Kotlin?

Update: More information as requested:

```
JDK Version: 11 (not Android, just pure JVM)
Kotlin Version:1.3.61
```

Comment: the reason of deprecation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195321/why-is-class-newinstance-evil/53014482#53014482)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this comes from Java itself. The appropriate replacement is:

```
T::class.java.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()
```

You can also check the [`Class.newInstance()`-Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()) which states that too.

Comment: `getDeclaredConstructor` (note the missing `s`) should work... it accepts a variable amount of parameter types...