# Is it possible to call method within a Java application from a different JVM?

Tags: java, jvm, init, ubuntu-12.04

When I first developed a Java service for Windows using Apache daemon, I used the `JVM` mode which I liked a lot. You specify your class and start\stop (static) methods. But with Linux, Jsvc doesn't look like it has the same option. I would really like to know why ?!

Anyway If I'm going to use Linux's init system, I'm trying to find a similar way to accomplish the same behavior which is to start the app in anyway but to stop it, I'll have to call a method in a class.

My question is, after the jar is started, how can I use the JVM libraries or anything else, to call a method in my application (which will attempt to stop my application **gracefully**).

Another side question, if an application is started and that application has static methods, If I use the `java` command line to run a `main` method in one if that's application class, and the `main` method, which is `static` would call another static method in the class in which I would like to signal the termination signal, would that call by in the same JVM?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not rather add a `ShutdownHook` to your application?

> A shutdown hook is simply an initialized but unstarted thread. When
>   the virtual machine begins its shutdown sequence it will start all
>   registered shutdown hooks in some unspecified order and let them run
>   concurrently. When all the hooks have finished it will then run all
>   uninvoked finalizers if finalization-on-exit has been enabled.
>   Finally, the virtual machine will halt. Note that daemon threads will
>   continue to run during the shutdown sequence, as will non-daemon
>   threads if shutdown was initiated by invoking the exit method.

This will allow your jar to terminate gracefully before being shutdown:

```
public class ShutdownHookDemo {
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Demo");
        ShutdownHook shutdownHook = new ShutdownHook();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(shutdownHook);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShutdownHookDemo demo = new ShutdownHookDemo();
        demo.start();
        try {
            System.in.read();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }
}

class ShutdownHook extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Shutting down");
        //terminate all other stuff for the application before it exits
    }

}
```

It is important to note

**The shutdown hook runs when:**

- A program exists normally. For example, System.exit() is called, or the last non-daemon thread exits.
- the Virtual Machine is terminated. e.g. CTRL-C. This corresponds to kill -SIGTERM pid or
- kill -15 pid on Unix systems.

**The shutdown hook will not run when:**

- The Virtual Machine aborts
- A SIGKILL signal is sent to the Virtual Machine process on Unix systems. e.g. kill -SIGKILL pid or kill -9 pid
- A TerminateProcess call is sent to the process on Windows systems.

Alternatively if you must you can use this to call a method in a class:

```
public class ReflectionDemo {

  public void print(String str, int value) {
    System.out.println(str);
    System.out.println(value);
  }

  public static int getNumber() { return 42; }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class<?> clazz = ReflectionDemo.class;//class name goes here
    // static call
    Method getNumber = clazz.getMethod("getNumber");
    int i = (Integer) getNumber.invoke(null /* static */);
    // instance call
    Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor();
    Object instance = ctor.newInstance();
    Method print = clazz.getMethod("print", String.class, Integer.TYPE);
    print.invoke(instance, "Hello, World!", i);
  }
}
```

and to load a class dynamically:

```
ClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(
    new URL[] { yourURL },
    getClass().getClassLoader()
);
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("mypackage.MyClass", true, loader);
Class<? extends Runnable> runClass = clazz.asSubclass(Runnable.class);
```

**References:**

- http://onjava.com/onjava/2003/03/26/shutdownhook.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)
- [How to shutdown java application correctly from C# one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11310530/how-to-shutdown-java-application-correctly-from-c-sharp-one/11311498#11311498)
- [How does one access a method from an external jar at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319661/how-does-one-access-a-method-from-an-external-jar-at-runtime)
- [How to load a jar file at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194698/how-to-load-a-jar-file-at-runtime)

Answer (score 2):

Basically the only way to call between JVMs is through the use of `Sockets`, either directly or via implementations based on it, such as `RMI`

You might lie to check out http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2000-03/03-qa-0324-ipc.html for further info