# Weird problem getting input from getInputStream

Tags: java

Here's my code:

```
    Runtime re = Runtime.getRuntime();
    BufferedReader output = null;    

    try{
            Process cmd = re.exec("java -jar myProg.jar " + myArgument); 
            output =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cmd.getInputStream()));
        }

    catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }

   String line;
   while ((line = output.readLine()) != null)
   {
    //process line
   }
```

When debugging this code snippet, I find that when reading each line from output, it skips certain lines.

If i run this myProg.jar from command line, the text that's seen on my command line is not 100% the same as what I get when I process the output from inside my java program!

What could cause this? The output is all text.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but instead of using a separate process, have you considered loading the class using a ClassLoader: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194698/how-to-load-a-jar-file-at-runtime - it might make things easier for you as you don't have to go via a command line - you can communicate with objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only appear to be reading standard out, whereas you may be getting output on standard error as well. I would read both.

Note that you need to read both streams *concurrently*, to avoid blocking. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882772/capturing-stdout-when-calling-runtime-exec/882795#882795) for more details.

Comment: Why would output be just randomly come out of standard error? doesnt' make sense to me. It's not an error, it's an output.