# Implementing a plugin interface

Tags: java, plugins

What's a good way of adding a plugin interface such that it's possible to have optional components?

I'm aware of the Class.forName() approach (used with JDBC for example) but there is also this approach to [dynamic class loading](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html).

Comment: Huh?  Dynamic class loading uses `Class.forName()`!

Comment: It would seem so. Question edited. Here's an article that explains the differences between the two: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2003-03/01-qa-0314-forname.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a look at this: http://jpf.sourceforge.net/.

A good approach would be to load jar files in a specified directory at runtime and look if they contain plugin classes. Have a look at this: [How to load a jar file at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194698/how-to-load-a-jar-file-at-runtime).

Comment: Thanks Simon. I'll have a look at those. If there's a second link to StackOverflow, I'd be interested in that too.

Comment: I found those links by searching 'java plugin architecture' on google