# Scan class or jar file in Java

Tags: java

I need to scan class or jar file that implements or extend a specific class.
It's the same mechanism that Eclipse use to scan the plugin presence.
There is a way to do this ?

Comment: there are ways, but you shouldn't need it ;)

Comment: @Bozho: Why not? Don't tell me you can smell it ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [exmaple depot: How to load a Class that is not on the classpath](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.lang/how-to-load-a-class-that-is-not-on-the-classpath-2.html):

```
// Create a File object on the root of the directory 
// containing the class file
File file = new File("c:\\class\\");

try {
    // Convert File to a URL
    URL url = file.toURL();          // file:/c:/class/
    URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

    // Create a new class loader with the directory
    ClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(urls);

    // Load in the class; Class.childclass should be located in
    // the directory file:/c:/class/user/information
    Class cls = loader.loadClass("user.informatin.Class");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
}
```

List the files in the directory if necessary, using `File.list()`.

When the class is loaded, you can check if it implements a specific interface by doing `clazz.isInstance`. From the docs:

> Determines if the specified Object is assignment-compatible with the object represented by this Class. This method is the dynamic **equivalent of the Java language instanceof  operator**.

---

To load classes from a jar-file:

[How to load a jar file at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194698/how-to-load-a-jar-file-at-runtime)

To list files in a jar file: `JarFile.entries()`.

Comment: If i would load it from jar ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are methods just to do that. Look at the docs [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

More specific links,

- [getGenericInterfaces()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericInterfaces%28%29)
- [getGenericSuperclass()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericSuperclass%28%29)

Comment: How can i load this specific class ?
I scan it but then i need also to load this only if it implements a specific interface.

Comment: @enfix: First you load it then you scan it, if it comply with your requirement use it, otherwise throw it.

Answer (score 0):

You can scan it without classloading it by using a bytecode parser such as ASM or BCEL.  With ASM...

```
byte[] bytecode = [read bytes from class or jar file];
ClassReader reader = new ClassReader( bytecode );
String[] interfaces = reader.getInterfaces();
```