# Problem reloading a jar using URLClassLoader

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, urlclassloader

I need to add plugin functionality to an existing application for certain parts of the application. I want to be able to add a jar at runtime and the application should be able to load a class from the jar without restarting the app. So far so good. I found some samples online using URLClassLoader and it works fine.

I also wanted the ability to reload the same class when an updated version of the jar is available. I again found some samples and the key to achieving this as I understand is that I need to use a new classloader instance for each new load.

I wrote some sample code but hit a NullPointerException. First let me show you guys the code:

```
package test.misc;

import java.io.File;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

import plugin.misc.IPlugin;

public class TestJarLoading {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        IPlugin plugin = null;

        while(true) {
            try {
                File file = new File("C:\\plugins\\test.jar");
                String classToLoad = "jartest.TestPlugin";
                URL jarUrl = new URL("jar", "","file:" + file.getAbsolutePath()+"!/");
                URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {jarUrl}, TestJarLoading.class.getClassLoader());
                Class loadedClass = cl.loadClass(classToLoad);
                plugin = (IPlugin) loadedClass.newInstance();
                plugin.doProc();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(30000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

IPlugin is a simple interface with just one method doProc:

```
public interface IPlugin {
    void doProc();
}
```

and jartest.TestPlugin is an implementation of this interface where doProc just prints out some statements.

Now, I package the jartest.TestPlugin class into a jar called test.jar and place it under C:\plugins and run this code. The first iteration runs smoothly and the class loads without issues.

When the program is executing the sleep statement, I replace C:\plugins\test.jar with a new jar containing an updated version of the same class and wait for the next iteration of while. Now here's what I don't understand. Sometimes the updated class gets reloaded without issues i.e. the next iteration runs fine. But sometimes, I see an exception thrown:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.FilterInputStream.close(FilterInputStream.java:155)
at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream.close(JarURLConnection.java:90)
at sun.misc.Resource.getBytes(Resource.java:137)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:256)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
at test.misc.TestJarLoading.main(TestJarLoading.java:22)
```

I have searched on the net and scratched my head but can't really arrive at any conclusion as to why this exception is thrown and that too - only sometimes, not always.

I need your experience and expertise to understand this. What's wrong with this code? Please help!!

Let me know if you need any more info. Thanks for looking!

Comment: Is there any chance you're replacing the JAR while it's still reading from the old one?

Comment: @Adam - I replace the jar once the class has been loaded and the doProc() method has executed. But let me try your suggestion by increasing the sleep time and replacing the jar a bit later. Will let you know how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: No success yet. As of now, it seems totally random whether it will succeed or fail on reloading. Not sure if there is something wrong with my environment. It will help if somebody else can try the code above on their machine. I am running it using Eclipse on Windows XP.

Comment: I've got some clues. Basically the problem seems to be that the old jar file is in use when I drop the new one and the resulting jar seems to be corrupt. However no helpful exception is thrown. I tried an alternate implementation where I defined my own version of classloader and there I was able to get a more accurate exception.

So the question is, is the jar file in the code above locked in use for the whole duration of the program (that seems to be the case)? How can I free it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This behaviour is related to a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5041014) in the jvm
2 workarounds are documented [here](http://management-platform.blogspot.com/2009/01/classloaders-keeping-jar-files-open.html)

Answer (score 18):

For everyone's benefit, let me summarize the real problem and the solution that worked for me.

As Ryan pointed out, there is a [bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=5041014) in JVM, which affects Windows Platform. `URLClassLoader` does not close the open jar files after it opens them for loading classes, effectively locking the jar files. The jar files can't be deleted or replaced.

The solution is simple: close the open jar files after they've been read. However, to get a handle to the open jar files, we need to use reflection since the properties we need to traverse down are not public. So we traverse down this path

```
URLClassLoader -> URLClassPath ucp -> ArrayList<Loader> loaders
JarLoader -> JarFile jar -> jar.close()
```

The code to close the open jar files can be added to a close() method in a class extending URLClassLoader:

```
public class MyURLClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {

public PluginClassLoader(URL[] urls, ClassLoader parent) {
    super(urls, parent);
}

    /**
     * Closes all open jar files
     */
    public void close() {
        try {
            Class clazz = java.net.URLClassLoader.class;
            Field ucp = clazz.getDeclaredField("ucp");
            ucp.setAccessible(true);
            Object sunMiscURLClassPath = ucp.get(this);
            Field loaders = sunMiscURLClassPath.getClass().getDeclaredField("loaders");
            loaders.setAccessible(true);
            Object collection = loaders.get(sunMiscURLClassPath);
            for (Object sunMiscURLClassPathJarLoader : ((Collection) collection).toArray()) {
                try {
                    Field loader = sunMiscURLClassPathJarLoader.getClass().getDeclaredField("jar");
                    loader.setAccessible(true);
                    Object jarFile = loader.get(sunMiscURLClassPathJarLoader);
                    ((JarFile) jarFile).close();
                } catch (Throwable t) {
                    // if we got this far, this is probably not a JAR loader so skip it
                }
            }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            // probably not a SUN VM
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

(This code was taken from the second link that Ryan posted. This code is also posted on the bug report page.)

**However, there's a catch:** For this code to work and be able to get a handle to the open jar files to close them, the loader used to load the classes from the file by URLClassLoader implementation has to be a `JarLoader`. Looking at the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/URLClassPath.java.html) of `URLClassPath` (method `getLoader(URL url)`), I noticed that it uses a JARLoader only if the file string used to create the URL does not end in "/". So, the URL must be defined like this:

```
URL jarUrl = new URL("file:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

The overall class loading code should look something like this:

```
void loadAndInstantiate() {
    MyURLClassLoader cl = null;
    try {
        File file = new File("C:\\jars\\sample.jar");
        String classToLoad = "com.abc.ClassToLoad";
        URL jarUrl = new URL("file:" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        cl = new MyURLClassLoader(new URL[] {jarUrl}, getClass().getClassLoader());
        Class loadedClass = cl.loadClass(classToLoad);
        Object o = loadedClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
    } finally {
        if(cl != null)
            cl.close();
    } 
}
```

**Update:** JRE 7 has introduced a `close()` method in the class [`URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#close%28%29) which may have solved this issue. I haven't verified it.

Comment: Many years later, still reproduced it on JDK/JRE 7, this time on the Mac. I am not sure there's a lock on the files, but the ClassLoader won't get finalized as soon as any of the JARs referenced by it are opened. I guess custom JAR loading is called for ... sigh.

Comment: @Samit G : after the instance is loaded , app would want to invoke a method with some argument which would process further, then If I am correct , I cannot close my classLoader? Any idea what do I do here?

Answer (score 4):

Starting from Java 7, you indeed have a `close()` method in `URLClassLoader` but it is not enough to release completely the jar files if you call directly or indirectly methods of type  `ClassLoader#getResource(String)`, `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream(String)` or `ClassLoader#getResources(String)`. Indeed by default, the `JarFile` instances are automatically stored into the cache of `JarFileFactory` in case we call directly or indirectly one of the previous methods and those instances are not released even if we call `java.net.URLClassLoader#close()`.

So a hack is still needed in this particular case even with Java 1.8.0_74, here is my hack https://github.com/essobedo/application-manager/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/essobedo/appma/core/util/Classpath.java#L83 that I use here https://github.com/essobedo/application-manager/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/essobedo/appma/core/DefaultApplicationManager.java#L388. Even with this hack, I still had to call the GC explicitly to fully release the jar files as you can see here https://github.com/essobedo/application-manager/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/essobedo/appma/core/DefaultApplicationManager.java#L419

Comment: @dalvarezmartinez1 Yes I know it is an old question, most of the answers here are out dated. I'm happy to know that my answer could help you :-)

Comment: Your code is the only one that works for me. After I call the release method I NEED to call loader.close() and then System.gc, this does it for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is **an update** tested on **java 7 with success**. Now the `URLClassLoader` works fine for me

### MyReloader

```
class MyReloaderMain {

...

//assuming ___BASE_DIRECTORY__/lib for jar and ___BASE_DIRECTORY__/conf for configuration
String dirBase = ___BASE_DIRECTORY__;

File file = new File(dirBase, "lib");
String[] jars = file.list();
URL[] jarUrls = new URL[jars.length + 1];
int i = 0;
for (String jar : jars) {
    File fileJar = new File(file, jar);
    jarUrls[i++] = fileJar.toURI().toURL();
    System.out.println(fileJar);
}
jarUrls[i] = new File(dirBase, "conf").toURI().toURL();

URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(jarUrls, MyReloaderMain.class.getClassLoader());

// this is required to load file (such as spring/context.xml) into the jar
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader);

Class classToLoad = Class.forName("my.app.Main", true, classLoader);

instance = classToLoad.newInstance();

Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod("start", args.getClass());
Object result = method.invoke(instance, args);

...
}
```

### Close and Restart the ClassReloader

then update your jar and call

```
classLoader.close();
```

then you can restart the app with the new version.

### Do not include your jar into your base class loader

Do not include your jar into your base class loader "`MyReloaderMain.class.getClassLoader()`" of the "`MyReloaderMain`", in other words develop 2 project with 2 jars one for "`MyReloaderMain`" and the other one for your real application without dependency between the two, or you will not able to understand who i loading what.

Comment: From op: "without restarting the app"

Answer (score 0):

The error is still present in `jdk1.8.0_2`5 on `Windows`. Although @Nicolas' answer helps, I hit a `ClassNotFound` for `sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory` when running it on WildFly, and several vm crashes while debugging some box tests...

Therefore I ended up extracting the part of the code which deals with loading and unloading, to an external jar. From the main code I just call this with `java -jar....` all looks fine for now.

**NOTE: Windows does release the locks on the loaded jar files when the jvm exits, that is why this works.**

Answer (score 0):

1. In principle, a class that has already been loaded cannot be reloaded with the same classloader.
2. For a new load, it is necessary to create a new classloader and thus load the class.
3. Using `URLClassLoader` has one problem and that is that the jar file remains open.
4. If you have multiple classes loaded from one jar file by different instances of `URLClassLoader` and you change the jar file at runtime, you will usually get this error: `java.util.zip.ZipException: ZipFile invalid LOC header (bad signature)`. The error may be different.
5. In order for the above errors not to occur, it is necessary to use the `close` method on all `URLClassLoader`s using the given jar file. But this is a solution that actually leads to a restart of the entire application.

A better solution is to modify the `URLClassLoader` so that the contents of the jar file are loaded into the RAM cache. This no longer affects other `URLClassloader`s that read data from the same jar file. The jar file can then be freely changed while the application is running. For example, you can use this modification of `URLClassLoader` for this purpose: [in-memory URLClassLoader](https://github.com/kotalr/b2b-jcl)