# Listing classes in a jar file

Tags: java, class, dynamic, urlclassloader

How can I dynamically load a jar file and list classes which is in it?

Comment: For those like me, who found this page because tried to find out how to list classes in jar in **command line**, not through Java, the answer is `jar tf yourfile.jar`

Comment: @Hnatt or any zip reader like 7-zip will work (for Windows), or even `unzip -l yourfile.jar` for *nix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have a look at the classes in the package `java.util.jar`. You can find examples of how to list the files inside the JAR on the web, here's [an example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/Listfilesinajarfile.htm). (Also note the links at the bottom of that page, there are many more examples that show you how to work with JAR files).

Comment: Thank you very much, and ".class" files is the classes? how can I load .class files as the classes?

Comment: So you want to load classes dynamically from a JAR file? That's much more than what you originally asked for. Maybe this question contains some answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194698/how-to-load-a-jar-file-at-runtime

Answer (score 16):

Here is code for listing classes in jar:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

public class JarList {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        if (args.length > 0) {
            JarFile jarFile = new JarFile(args[0]);
            Enumeration allEntries = jarFile.entries();
            while (allEntries.hasMoreElements()) {
                JarEntry entry = (JarEntry) allEntries.nextElement();
                String name = entry.getName();
                System.out.println(name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can view the contents of a JAR file from command prompt by using the following command:

```
jar tf jar-file
```

For example:

```
jar tf TicTacToe.jar


META-INF/MANIFEST.MF  
TicTacToe.class  
audio/  
audio/beep.au  
audio/ding.au  
audio/return.au  
audio/yahoo1.au  
audio/yahoo2.au  
images/  
images/cross.gif  
images/not.gif
```

Answer (score 4):

Fast way: just open the .jar as .zip e.g. in 7-Zip and look for the directory-names.

Comment: This works really well if you don't have the `jar` command on your station and don't want to install it just for this one check

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that scans a given jar for all *non-abstract* classes extending a particular class:

```
try (JarFile jf = new JarFile("/path/to/file.jar")) {
    for (Enumeration<JarEntry> en = jf.entries(); en.hasMoreElements(); ) {
        JarEntry e = en.nextElement();
        String name = e.getName();
        // Check for package or sub-package (you can change the test for *exact* package here)
        if (name.startsWith("my/specific/package/") && name.endsWith(".class")) {
            // Strip out ".class" and reformat path to package name
            String javaName = name.substring(0, name.lastIndexOf('.')).replace('/', '.');
            System.out.print("Checking "+javaName+" ... ");
            Class<?> cls;
            try {
                cls = Class.forName(javaName);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)  { // E.g. internal classes, ...
                continue;
            }
            if ((cls.getModifiers() & Modifier.ABSTRACT) != 0) { // Only instanciable classes
                System.out.println("(abstract)");
                continue;
            }
            if (!TheSuper.class.isAssignableFrom(cls)) { // Only subclasses of "TheSuper" class
                System.out.println("(not TheSuper)");
                continue;
            }
            // Found!
            System.out.println("OK");
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can use that code directly when you know where are your jars. To get that information, refer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613988/how-to-get-classpath-from-classloader), as going through classpath has changed since Java 9 and the introduction of modules.