# Java Classpath in context

Tags: java, classpath

I'm writing a program, which needs to known all classes/jars in its context. For example if it runs in a Maven environment, it must know the path to all of the dependent jars in .m2/. If it runs in Tomcat, it must know the jars in `WEB-INF/lib/`. It should do this automatically, without any configuration. I have used `System.getProperty("java.class.path")` but it does not work in Tomcat.

Comment: If it runs in Tomcat, Tomcat will set up the classpath automatically. Similarly, if run through Maven, Maven does it. Why does your app have to do itself?

Comment: It must call the java compiler in Runtime to compile java code, which also are generated in Runtime. So the java compiler needs to known the necessary jars (in context) to compile the java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a similar question has been asked before.
You will need to get the JARs loaded from the SystemClassLoader.

```
((URLClassLoader) (Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader())).getURLs()
```

See this link for further details.

[How to get classpath from classloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613988/how-to-get-classpath-from-classloader)

Comment: Well I had found the solution: Three _Contexts_ must be checked: The System's ClassLoader, the `getContextClassLoader` and the last one: `this.getClass().getClassLoader()`. Then it should work.