# How do I get path of my application's binaries?

Tags: java, scala

i.e. I need to get path of the directory from where my classes are loaded.

Comment: Launch your app with `java -verbose:class`. Make sure you have enough buffer in your terminal, it is very verbose. Or redirect to a file or use grep for easier searching.

Comment: @StephaneM, from within the program.

Comment: The last answer from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613988/how-to-get-classpath-from-classloader may be what you want.

Comment: @StephaneM, why don't make it an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last answer from this thread: [How to get classpath from classloader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613988/how-to-get-classpath-from-classloader) may be what you want:

```
ClassLoader cl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) cl).getURLs();
for (URL url: urls) {
    System.out.println(url.getFile());
}
```