# Loading classes and resources post Java 9

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-9, java-platform-module-system, module-path

I was reading [this article on InfoQ](https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/06/oracle-defends-jpms) quoting Reinhold:

> Developers can still use the Java class path in Java 9 for the Java
>   runtime to search for classes and resource files. It's just that with
>   Java 9's modules, developers no longer need the class path.

So now my question is: what is the proper Java 9 way to do the tasks listed above? How do you dynamically load e.g. an image (short of fiddling with relative paths)?

Even more interestingly, how would one check if a class is available and make a decision dynamically (e.g. check if Jackson is available and, if so, use it for JSON serialization and if not use something else)?

The article also mentions Spring Boot already supporting Java 9, and Spring Boot definitely does a lot of dynamic loading. So maybe someone knows the priece of code from Spring that I can look at?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

First, to set the record straight, I neither said nor wrote the text
quoted above.  I’d never have put it that way.  That’s just sloppy
reporting on the part of the publications involved.

The most important thing to understand about class loading and resource
lookup in Java 9 is that, at a fundamental level, they have not changed.
You can search for classes and resources in the same way that you always
have, by invoking `Class::forName` and the various `getResource*` methods
in the `Class` and `ClassLoader` classes, regardless of whether your code
is loaded from the class path or the module path.  There are still three
built-in class loaders, just as there were in JDK 1.2, and they have the
same delegation relationships.  Lots of existing code therefore just
works, out-of-the-box.

There are some nuances, as noted in [JEP
261](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#Class-loaders): The concrete type
of the built-in class loaders has changed, and some classes formerly
loaded by the bootstrap class loader are now loaded by the platform class
loader in order to improve security.  Existing code which assumes that a
built-in class loader is a `URLClassLoader`, or that a class is loaded by
the bootstrap class loader, may therefore require minor adjustments.

A final important difference is that non-class-file resources in a module
are encapsulated by default, and hence [cannot be located from outside
the module unless their effective package is
`open`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Module.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-).
To load resources from your own module it’s best to use the
resource-lookup methods in `Class` or `Module`, which can locate any
resource in your module, rather than those in `ClassLoader`, which can
only locate non-class-file resources in the `open` packages of a module.

Answer (score 6):

[Edit: this answer was written prior to Mark's authoritative answer. I've revised mine to provide a simple example, available [on GitHub](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_java_9/tree/master/egg_31_stack_overflow_45166757).]

Per [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fxB9cVNcyZo&feature=youtu.be&t=26m28s), class loading in Java 9 is unchanged.

As an example, let's say we have:

- an `example.jar` that contains an image in the package `net.codetojoy.example.resources`
- to beef up the jar, `net.codetojoy.example.Composer` is public (and exported, where applicable)
- a simple `App` class that uses `example.jar` as a library and attempts to load the image from it

The relevant code in `App`:

```
static InputStream getResourceAsStream(String resource) 
    throws Exception {

    // Load net/codetojoy/example/resource/image.jpg
    // Assume net.codetojoy.example.Composer is public/exported
    // resource is 'resource/image.jpg'

    InputStream result = Composer.class.getResourceAsStream(resource);

    return result;
}
```

Here are a few cases for `example.jar` in JDK 9:

**Old-Fashioned, Non-Modular Jar**

If `example.jar` is not a module, the code just works. Class loading is unchanged.

**Modular Jar With Open Package**

In this case, this is the `module-info.java` file:

```
module net.codetojoy.example {
    // export the Composer class
    exports net.codetojoy.example;

    // image is available
    opens net.codetojoy.example.resources;
}
```

In this case, the image can be loaded by the client, because the package is open.

**Modular Jar Without Open Package**

In this case, `module-info.java` is:

```
module net.codetojoy.example {
    // export the Composer class
    exports net.codetojoy.example;

    // package not opened: image not available
    // opens net.codetojoy.example.resources;
}
```

In this case, the image cannot be loaded, because of strong encapsulation: the module is protecting the image by not opening the package.

Full source [here on GitHub](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_java_9/tree/master/egg_31_stack_overflow_45166757).

Comment: Thanks, but what about those using an older language level where `module-info.java` isn't supported, but we're still running into walls with the resource loader?  Is there any concession for developers looking to play nicely with JRE9 without yet adopting the new JDK9 language level?

Comment: Nevermind, my issue was the use of `Foo.class.getClass().getResourceAsStream(...)` versus `Foo.class.getResourceAsStream(...)`.  JDK9 seems to handle the former  differently than JDK8, JDK7.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the existing answers I’d like to give an example of encapsulation rules for non-class-file resources for different resource directory names.

The specification for [getResourceAsStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Module.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) says that the resource is encapsulated if a *package name* is derived from its name.

So if the [resource’s directory name is NOT a valid Java identifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html), it is NOT encapsulated. Which means that if a module has a resource located under, for example, a directory named `dir-1` (containing a non-valid character `-` in its name) it will always be accessible from outside of the module.

Here is an example of two Java modules ([source code in GitHub](https://github.com/agavrilov76/jpms-resource)). *Module 1* consists of the following resource files:

```
├── dir-3
│   └── resource3.txt
├── dir1
│   └── resource1.txt
├── dir2
│   └── resource2.txt
└── root.txt
```

and `module-info.java`:

```
module module_one {
  opens dir1;
}
```

*Module 2* requires *Module 1* in `module-info.java`:

```
module module_two {
  requires module_one;
}
```

and has a sample main class for loading various resource files:

```
package module2;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    loadResource("root.txt", "From module's root directory");
    loadResource("dir1/resource1.txt", "From opened package `dir1`");
    loadResource("dir2/resource2.txt", "From internal package `dir2`");
    loadResource("dir-3/resource3.txt", "From directory `dir-3` with non-Java name");
  }

  public static void loadResource(String name, String comment) throws IOException {
    // module2 application class loader
    final var classLoader = Main.class.getClassLoader();
    try (var in = classLoader.getResourceAsStream(name)) {
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("// " + comment);
      System.out.println(name + ": " + (in != null));
    }
  }
}
```

Running the class above gives the following output:

```
// From module's root directory
root.txt: true

// From opened package `dir1`
dir1/resource1.txt: true

// From internal package `dir2`
dir2/resource2.txt: false

// From directory `dir-3` with non-Java name
dir-3/resource3.txt: true
```

As you can see the resource file from the root directory and from the `dir-3` directory are not encapsulated, therefore *Module 2* can load them.

The package `dir1` is encapsulated but unconditionally opened. *Module 2* can load it as well.

The package `dir2` is encapsulated and not opened. *Module 2* cannot load it.

Note that *Module 2* cannot contain their own resources under `dir1` and `dir2` directories because they are already encapsulated in *Module 1*. If you try adding `dir1` you will get the following error:

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.LayerInstantiationException: Package dir1 in both module module_one and module module_two
```

Here is a [Flyway related issue](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/3196) for reference.

Comment: I can not agree, I am no expert in module system, but I could not load any resources from a moduleA when not using a class loader from this moduleA. Even within a qualified identifier it was not visible.