# Netbeans Java Modular project - resource folder

Tags: java, netbeans, module

How can i load resources in a Netbeans (12.3)Java modular project?
And where can i put te resources folder?

If you look in te New project wizard, there are no modular project with Maven, so i created an Ant project.

I have created a test project, called Resources, with a module test
The goal of Java modules is to control it own resources, so i create the resources folder in the test module.

The directory structure of the test module:

test

- classes
- resources
- tests

But the resources directory is not visible in Netbeans itself. If you go to project settings / sources you can add folders to sources, it won't work either:
[image]

The resources folder must in the module folder because every module becomes a jar file.
How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have found it!

A good explanation:
[Loading classes and resources in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45166757/loading-classes-and-resources-in-java-9)

You must put the resources module in the classes directory
The recourses folder appears in Netbeans and can be loaded in the application (if the resources is openend in module-info.java)