# How to enumerate non-system modules in Java 9

Tags: java, classpath, java-9, java-module

Update: I answered my own question here:

[Scanning classpath/modulepath in runtime in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932635/scanning-classpath-modulepath-in-runtime-in-java-9/45612376#45612376)

--

[Old question -- obsolete:]

In the Java 9 module system, you can find system modules using

```
Set<ModuleReference> ms = ModuleFinder.ofSystem().findAll();
```

These `ModuleReference` objects can then be used to list the contents of each module, using:

```
for (ModuleReference m : ms) {
    System.out.println(m.descriptor().name());
    System.out.println(" " + m.descriptor().toNameAndVersion());
    System.out.println(" " + m.descriptor().packages());
    System.out.println(" " + m.descriptor().exports());
    Optional<URI> location = m.location();
    if (location.isPresent()) {
        System.out.println(" " + location.get()); // e.g. "jrt:/java.base"
    }
    m.open().list().forEach(s -> System.out.println("  " + s));
}
```

And to get the module of the current class, you can use

```
Module m = getClass().getModule();
```

but I can't seem to get a `ModuleReference` from this `Module` (so I can't list the contents of the module, other than the packages), and the non-system `Module`s are not listed by `ModuleFinder`.

Two questions:

1. How do I enumerate the resources in non-system modules?
2. How are non-module classpaths read in JRE 9? Am I just supposed to rely on the `java.class.path` system property? (The `AppClassLoader#ucp` field of type `URLClassPath` is not visible, and is locked down in JRE 9, so you can't get it by introspection either.)

Comment: I guess the highlighted portion of your question shall be to get the URI(location/path) for modules? then I guess you are just bothered about the non-system modules, is that true? Since all the other attributes of your code are accessible via ModuleDescriptor which is an [entity of a Module](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Module.html#getDescriptor--) itself. Also AFAIR this could possibly be a duplicate of a similar question. Would await for you to confirm the details.

Comment: Just taking a blind shot(without the details in the question), you might be interested in the [`ModuleLayer` of a `Module`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Module.html#getLayer--). If you look at the example in the link there, you can find configuration and the layer using the directory of modules via ModuleFinder.

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
Set<String> systemModuleNames = ModuleFinder
        .ofSystem()
        .findAll()
        .stream()
        .map(moduleRef -> moduleRef.descriptor().name())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

List<Module> nonSystemModules = ModuleLayer
        .boot()
        .modules()
        .stream()
        .filter(m -> !systemModuleNames.contains(m.getName()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(nonSystemModules);
```

Now when you have `nonSystemModules`, you can do anything you want with this list (e.g. get resources in each module).

Comment: Thanks @ZhekaKozlov. This unfortunately doesn't work for automatic (unnamed) modules, which it turns out is what I need to handle (specifically, automatic modules are not returned by `ModuleLayer.boot().modules()`). Do you know how to get a list of automatic modules?

Re. question (2): What I'm referring to is the ability to add non-module classfiles to the classpath in Java 9. Are these always converted to automatic modules? I believe I read that the JRE still honors `java.class.path` and the `-cp` switch.

For context, what I'm trying to accomplish is classpath scanning.