# is there a java 11 replacement to get all jars in classpath with maven exec:java?

Tags: java, maven

I have a code that currently gets all jars from the classpath:

```
final URLClassLoader loader = (URLClassLoader) MyClass.class.getClassLoader();
URL[] urls = loader.getURLs();
```

This works fine with Java 8, but not in Java 11.

In Java 11 we have to change the mechanism to use `System.getProperty("java.class.path")`

This works ok, but breaks when using `mvn exec:java` because the classloader in that plugin is `plexus`.
The only jar in the classpath is `/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.6.0/libexec/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar`.

Is there a way to get all the jars for this maven plugin or classloader?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanning classpath/modulepath in runtime in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41932635/5221149)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: The full code is resolving properties from yaml file with name correspond to each jar file loaded.