# Patch Java 9 module with test-code to work with reflections

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

How do I add my tests to my production code at test-runtime so that both are in the same Java 9 module and can access each other using reflections?

I have tried so far:

- Remove the Java 9 modularity (actually the `module-info.java`) → it worked perfectly, but is not what I'm looking for.
- Move my tests to a dedicated module (and therefore also package) → it worked perfectly, but is not what I'm looking for. (I want my Unit-Tests near my code.)
- Use `--patch-module` to virtually add another folder (to the one specified using `--module-path`) → it worked with "normal" code but not with reflections, it doesn't find the classes specified by `--module-path`.

  - Specify both my test and production code using `--patch-module` → it only finds classes in the folder I specify first.
  - Explicitly add `--add-opens mymodule/mypackge=mymodule` or `...=ALL-UNNAMED` to open it for reflection → doesn't look to have any effect.

So my full test line is:

```
java \
  --patch-module com.stackoverflow.examplemodule=ModuleInfoTest:ModuleInfoExample \
  --module-path ModuleInfoExample \
  --add-opens com.stackoverflow.examplemodule/com.stackoverflow.examplepackage=com.stackoverflow.examplemodule \
  --add-opens com.stackoverflow.examplemodule/com.stackoverflow.examplepackage=ALL-UNNAMED \
  --module com.stackoverflow.examplemodule/com.stackoverflow.examplepackage.Main
```

I'm in a directory containing the following subdirectories and files:

- ModuleInfoExample/module-info.class
- ModuleInfoExample/com/stackoverflow/examplepackage/Main.class
- ModuleInfoTest/com/stackoverflow/examplepackage/AnyClass.class

I'm using:

```
openjdk version "13.0.2" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13.0.2+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

---

---

---

> As I learned from the approved answer, my problem was not really "*access* other classes", as I phrased it. But more like *find* them (by scanning classpath/modulepath). However this part is already [answered in this other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41932635/scanning-classpath-modulepath-in-runtime-in-java-9).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Oracle's Java 13 java command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/java.html) these are the two options you tried to use:

```
--add-opens module/package=target-module(,target-module)*
--patch-module module=file(;file)*
```

but:

- `--add-opens` doesn't help you because it opens up one module to other modules. You only have one module.
- `--patch-module` must specify the directories (or jarfiles) you want to patch into the module. I noticed that there's a `;` not a `:` like you used. It seems to me that you've been telling java to patch files from same the directory where your module is at with `:ModuleInfoExample`.

You only need to add the files from `ModuleInfoTest/` into your module.
I created the structure from your Question and ran it:

#### Compiling:

```
javac -d target/ModuleInfoExample src/ModuleInfoExample/*.java src/ModuleInfoExample/com/stackoverflow/examplepackage/*.java
javac -cp target/ModuleInfoExample -d target/ModuleInfoTest src/ModuleInfoTest/com/stackoverflow/examplepackage/*.java
```

#### Running Main from module - no added classes:

```
java --module-path target/ModuleInfoExample --module com.stackoverflow.examplemodule/com.stackoverflow.examplepackage.Main

prints:
Hello world - I'm private
```

#### Running AnyClass from module - no added classes - exception expected

```
java --module-path target/ModuleInfoExample --module com.stackoverflow.examplemodule/com.stackoverflow.examplepackage.AnyClass

Error: Could not find or load main class com.stackoverflow.examplepackage.AnyClass in module com.stackoverflow.examplemodule
```

#### Running AnyClass from module - adding AnyClass into the package:

```
java --module-path target/ModuleInfoExample --patch-module com.stackoverflow.examplemodule=target/ModuleInfoTest --module com.stackoverflow.examplemodule/com.stackoverflow.examplepackage.AnyClass

prints:
Inside AnyClass - calling Main: Hello world - I'm private

  field.get() = I'm private
  field.get() = I'm not private anymore
```

#### Total structure:

```
>tree /f
..snip..
C:.
+---src
¦   +---ModuleInfoExample
¦   ¦   ¦   module-info.java
¦   ¦   ¦
¦   ¦   +---com
¦   ¦       +---stackoverflow
¦   ¦           +---examplepackage
¦   ¦                   Main.java
¦   ¦
¦   +---ModuleInfoTest
¦       +---com
¦           +---stackoverflow
¦               +---examplepackage
¦                       AnyClass.java
¦
+---target
    +---ModuleInfoExample
    ¦   ¦   module-info.class
    ¦   ¦
    ¦   +---com
    ¦       +---stackoverflow
    ¦           +---examplepackage
    ¦                   Main.class
    ¦
    +---ModuleInfoTest
        +---com
            +---stackoverflow
                +---examplepackage
                        AnyClass.class
```

#### src\ModuleInfoExample\module-info.java:

```
module com.stackoverflow.examplemodule {
//  exports com.stackoverflow.examplepackage; // no need to export. Nothing is using this
}
```

#### src\ModuleInfoExample\com\stackoverflow\examplepackage\Main.java:

```
package com.stackoverflow.examplepackage;

public class Main {
  private String privateString = "I'm private";

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main().hello();
  }
  public void hello(){
    System.out.println("Hello world - " + privateString);
  }
}
```

#### src\ModuleInfoTest\com\stackoverflow\examplepackage\AnyClass.java:

```
package com.stackoverflow.examplepackage;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;

public class AnyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    testhello();
    System.out.println();
    breakhello();
  }

  public static void testhello(){
    System.out.print("Inside AnyClass - calling Main: ");
    Main test = new Main();
    test.hello();
  }

  public static void breakhello(){
    try {
      // Not necessary - same package, but..
      Class<?> mainClass = Class.forName("com.stackoverflow.examplepackage.Main");
      Constructor<?> constructor = mainClass.getConstructor();
      Object main = constructor.newInstance();

      // Getting, printing and changing the field..
      Field field = mainClass.getDeclaredField("privateString");
      field.setAccessible(true);
      System.out.println("  field.get() = " + field.get(main));
      field.set(main,"I'm not private anymore");
      System.out.println("  field.get() = " + field.get(main));

    } catch (Exception e) {  // Sorry, all in one big bucket
       System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This indeed seems to work with this kind of reflection. However I would like to "find" the other classes. I've added some code to my question and pasted it also in your `AnyClass`. It only finds itself. When I run it with `java --class-path target/ModuleInfoExample:target/ModuleInfoTest com.stackoverflow.examplepackage.AnyClass` (so without modules), it finds both classes. I suspect it's a bug in Java...

Comment: @Itchy I may look at it. However, I answered based on your Question. I'm feeling a bit of scope-creeping coming on. I don't think it's a bug in java.

Comment: I am very grateful for your answer - that's why I already gave it an upvote. I guess the problem is, I was not fully aware about the full scope of the term "reflections". For me it was basically just "finding classes" (which obviously isn't all there is).

Comment: @Itchy I understand your peril, but your new "requirements" has partially invalidated my answer. I'd much prefer that you rollback your edit to this Question and create a new Question with the new problem. Feel free to use the parts of my answer in your new Question.

Comment: I see your point. And a new question is currently not needed, meanwhile I found a corresponding question thanks to the learning from your answer. So I've reverted and updated my question. Thanks a lot again for your time!