How to get a list of dependent jars within Tomcat during runtime?
I want to have a listing of all jars that are included in my application during runtime (Java 8 compatible). Therefore I fetch all files that ends with .jar from the classpath (System.getProperty("java.class.path");) incl. recursive search in folders within the classpath.
When I start the application locally with SpringBoot everything works fine as expected.  But when I build a war archive out of my code and deploy it on a Tomcat my methode call only returns:

bootstrap.jar
tomcat-juli.jar
wrapper.jar

Is there another classpath available in Tomcat? What is the best way to support SpringBoot and Tomcat in parallel? At the end I want to have the name of the jar file and some information out of the manifest within the jars. At the moment I fetch the manifest file with new JarInputStream(is).getManifest() (simplified code snippet, is is the InputStream of the file).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11613988/how-to-get-classpath-from-classloader

Thanks for the hint. Meanwhile I also did some experiments with classloaders (using Java 17) without success. The ClassGraph lib sounds quite interesting although they mentioned some possible problems for higher Java versions. I will give it a try.

Are the jars present in the war? Does the app work?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10230279/java-verbose-class-loading

Yes, the jars are in the war archive and the application is working fine. I think the jars are handled by a classloader somehow.
