# Is it possible to load library at runtime?

Tags: java, urlclassloader

Is there a way to load a java library (.jar file) at runtime, if it is not on the classpath?

Comment: I have not dealt much with libraries*, but you might try using an URLClassLoader to get access to it.  * BTW - by 'library' do you mean natives?

Comment: No, I mean just a simple java library. (a .jar file)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. I am voting to close this because google "java load jar dynamically" gave me a few decent SO answers and a number of other useful examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I load Jars dynamically at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime) -- also see [How to load a jar file at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194698/how-to-load-a-jar-file-at-runtime), etc.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson - your approach works, but it loads only one class at a time. Is there a way to load entire library?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson - I found that all other classes are loaded automatically when I call them. Thanks. (If you'll post your answer, I'll select it)

Comment: @pst - forgive me, haven't noticed that before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
URLClassLoader child = new URLClassLoader (myJar.toURL(), this.getClass().getClassLoader());
Class classToLoad = Class.forName ("com.MyClass", true, child);
Method method = classToLoad.getDeclaredMethod ("myMethod");
Object instance = classToLoad.newInstance ();
Object result = method.invoke (instance);
```

Source: [How should I load Jars dynamically at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime)

Comment: `Important Comment From Source:` Using this approach you need to make sure you won't call this load method more than once for each class. Since you're creating a new class loader for every load operation, it can not know whether the class was already loaded previously. This can have bad consequences. For example singletons not working because the class was loaded several times and so the static fields exist several times