# Java import, without CLASSPATH

Tags: java, classloader

Is there a way to import other classes in Java without adding them to the classpath? Something like "import C:/dir/file.jar"?

Comment: [How to load a jar file at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194698/how-to-load-a-jar-file-at-runtime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't import a jar file just by changing the "import". But you can using the class loader. See [How to load a jar file at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194698/how-to-load-a-jar-file-at-runtime)

```
File file  = new File("C:\\dir\\file.jar");
URL url = file.toURL();  
ClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader( new URL[]{ file.toURL() } );
Class cls = classLoader.loadClass("mypackage.myclass");
```