# JavaCompiler giving NullPointerException on "ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler()". I'm pretty sure I have JDK set up right?

Tags: compiler-construction, nullpointerexception, java

The section of code in question is:

```
String fileToCompile = "C:/Users/Jeff/Documents/Test/Compiler 6/examplejavafile.java";//Absolute path
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
FileOutputStream errorStream = new FileOutputStream("Errors.txt");
int compilationResult = compiler.run(null, null, errorStream, "-verbose", fileToCompile);
if(compilationResult == 0){
    System.out.println("Compilation is successful");
}else{
    System.out.println("Compilation Failed");
}
```

When I run this section of code it gives me NPE on:

```
JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
```

Now I've been told that this is an error in the environment, but I have JDK installed and my CLASSPATH variable is set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin".  I might be a noob and not understand how to run a program through JDK instead of JRE, but regardless I need help. (Also, I am using Eclipse, if it's any different.)

Comment: How can _that_ line give a NPE?  What does the stack trace look like?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to import the ToolProvider since it is not defined, unless you just didn't include that information.

```
import javax.tools.ToolProvider;
```

Comment: Yes I have imported all the necessary tools.  It's a console error on runtime.

Comment: Hmm, I can't seem to see why that line would throw a NPE or even the line before it. I just ran the code and it seems to work fine on Ubuntu. Sorry :(

Comment: Please consider another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403655/javacompiler-returning-null). In two words - if you are on Windows then check if JAVA_HOME points to JDK and not runtime environment.

Answer (score 0):

Look up the Run Configuration for the project (under the Run menu). Under JRE is should specify the project execution environment is using 'JavaSE-1.6' (jsk1.6.20_32) or such.

Comment: This makes sense, but the only options I see there say (jre7), which leads me to believe that I installed JDK wrong; Is there something I need to do to eclipse to update my installation?

Answer (score 0):

ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler() is not available.

Is tools.jar missing from the classpath?

`Set class path to the tools.jar` file which can found in jdk\jre directory.

`System.setProperty("java.home", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_02");`