# How can I know at runtime if a JAR file is already in the classpath?

Tags: java, classpath, classloader, noclassdeffounderror

What is the best way to know at runtime if a particular JAR file is already in my classpath ? (if that is not the case I should add it at runtime).

I do not know in advance the name of the jar nor the classes in it. A user can select it. The jar represents a runtime plugable component (a driver in my problem).

Comment: Take a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory

Answer (score 3):

```
String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path")
```

this will give you what is on your classpath. you can then parse that for the jar file you want

Comment: Use java.io.File.pathSeparatorChar to get the OS dependent character that can be used in String.split(...) to break this up.

Answer (score 3):

A pragmatic way: `Class.forName("com.myclass")` where `com.myclass` is a class that is inside (and only inside) your target jar; if that throws a `ClassNotFoundException`, then the jar is not on you current classpath.

Bear in mind, though, that [loading a jar at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194698/how-to-load-a-jar-file-at-runtime) is not very simple, you need to mess with classloaders.
As a rule (there are exceptions) that's not the way, you should be able to add explicitly the jar to the classpath before running.

Update: the updated question states that we don't know in advance "the name of the jar nor the classes in it"; if so, this answer obviously does not apply. And the answer will depend on your specific classloader. In the  usual scenario, AlexAndas' answer should work.

Comment: *"Bear in mind, though, that loading a jar at runtime is not very simple"*  It only requires a handful of lines of code.  What is so hard about that?

Comment: @AndrewThompson The hard thing might be the pitfalls when loading the same class with different classloaders and then wondering why instances of these classes are not exchangeable.

Comment: @leonbloy the restriction "where com.myclass is a class that is inside (and only inside) your target jar" cannot be fulfilled in the situation of this problem: "I do not know in advance the name of the jar nor the classes in it."

Comment: @mschenk74 Yes, that restriction was added after my answer, I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

try using this method:

```
public static void isJarExist(String jarName)
    {
        ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        if (classLoader instanceof URLClassLoader)
        {
            URLClassLoader classLoader2 = (URLClassLoader) classLoader;
            URL [] urls = classLoader2.getURLs();
            for (URL url : urls)
            {
                File file = new File(url.getFile());
                if (file.getPath().endsWith(jarName))
                {
                    System.out.println(jarName + " exist");
                    return;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(jarName + " not exist");
        }
    }
```

just pass your jar like isJarExist("myjar.jar), you can also modify it to return boolean as you wish

Comment: but what if the system class loader is not a URLClassLoader ? (although probably this is not a common situation)

Comment: I don't know, I also found this solution when searched how to load all classes from classpath. It works fine for me. I think that default implementation of ClassLoader is URLClassLoader, but I can be wrong.

Comment: The ClassLoader is custom, for instance, when unit testing using Maven Surefire. In that case, you'll only find a few jars which are contrived by Surefire. Solution: Use the System Property (see RNJ's answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in general since there might be classloaders in your application that don't offer information of the jar-files. 
In the case of URLClassLoaders, you can use the solution of Alex Adas