# How to add an external .jar to the build path via code

Tags: java, jar

I am working on a program that will allow for modular addons to be installed by simply dropping the correct .jar file into a folder. I was not quite sure how to add a file like this to the build path and use a method from that file. I know how to do this if I know exactly what file I will be using, but in this case I do not. I will need to be able to run a method from the external jar without telling eclipse ahead of time that this is the file I will be using.

Comment: If you use Java 7, you can define a directory and load all jars from there when running `java`. Not sure of the correct syntax, you can check it yourself.

Comment: Will this work for java 6 as well? I used to compile on Java 7, but I had issues with people saying it doesn't work because they used Java 6. I am willing to switch to Java 7 again if necessary, but I would prefer to stay on Java 6 for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the jar using method described on this answer: [How to load a jar file at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194698/how-to-load-a-jar-file-at-runtime)

I would assume you also need an interface to act as a binding contract so you know what to cast your class to