# Not seeing any output when using a different classloader

Tags: java, thread-safety, classloader, output

So here's my issue:

I have some code that is being called when a certain event happens on a DocuShare server.  I listen for the event in my own eventlistener.  So far so good, this works without issue.

This listener will call other code that is developed separately and resides in its own jar file.

Currently we have the overhead of always having to shut down the entire system to deploy a new version of one of those jars so it can be used.

So now I am trying to create a system that copies that jarfile (not on the classpath) to another temp location (so no jarlock), loads the jarfile in its own different classloader and executes it.  This way I can simply overwrite the original jarfile when a new version is developed.  The code will then see if there was a modification to the jarfile and do the same steps if that's the case.

I have done this successfully in a simpler setup (a servlet being called) so I know the approach of 'hot deploying' the jars works.

However, in this case, the code works fine up until I start using the separate classloader.
I can find the jarfile and check for differences and load the jarfile accordingly but when I try to access the class I don't get any output in System.out or System.err anymore.  The code in the jar is not being executed properly but I can't see why.

Extra info: the code is being executed in its own Thread

Overview of whats happening:

1. DocuShare sends an event
2. My listener picks up the event
3. The listener (implements java.util.concurrent.Executor) starts a new Thread (Runnable impl)
4. The Runnable impl creates a new classloader and then checks if there is a new version of the jar file inside a folder, if so it will copy it to another dir, if not it uses the existing version, load it on the classpath of the new classloader and execute it
5. Fromt the moment I load a class with the new ClassLoader I don't see any line printed in the System.out/System.err.

code example (in the Runnable.run() method):

```
URLClassLoader hotCL = new URLClassLoader(((URLClassLoader) systemCL).getURLs()); //new URLclassloader with URLs from system CL

//the following approach for putting the class on the classpath comes from another SO question from somebody else
Method m = cl.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
m.setAccessible(true);
m.invoke(cl, jar.toURI().toURL());
String cp = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
if (cp != null) {
    cp += File.pathSeparatorChar + jar.getCanonicalPath();
} else {
    cp = jar.toURI().getPath();
}

Logger.log(">>>>>>>> instantiating impl");  //this is printed in the System.out
Class<?> clsService = hotCL.loadClass(strService);  //strService is the class inside the separate jar
Object instance = clsService.newInstance();

Logger.log(">>>>>>>>>>>> class: " + clsService.getClass().toString()); //this is not printed in the System.out, neither is any log-statement after this or any error
//after this a method of the class instance is called but the code doesn't do anything.  Possibly an error but there's no error/stacktrace
```

Is there something I'm missing about ClassLoaders?  I just don't get why I don't see any error or code being executed.

Comment: i would have tagged it as 'docushare' aswell but it requires 1500 points

Comment: Sounds like your thread is dieing silently on an exception. Try putting your code in a try-catch block and printing the exception. Note that it won't bubble up to the command line like it would in the main thread - see here for further reading http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp0924/

Comment: `newInstance` can throw exceptions for lots of reasons - does the class your loading have an empty constructor?

Comment: First, surround loadclass and newinstance with try/catch block; second, print possible catched errors directly to System.out/System.err.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll read that.  The class does not have any constructor defined (so default should be available).  I can instantiate the class reflectively in other applications (using Class.forName() or ClassLoader.loadClass().

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov There is a try-catch block around all of the code above (and the part where the method is executed at the end.  Do you mean not using the Logger class? Although it **only** does System.out.println?

Comment: If Logger does not print, it's natural to try other way :). And put one more debugging printing between loadClass and newInstance. Does your catch block catch all Throwables?

Comment: To avoid reflection, try to declare you classloader as URLClassLoader hotCL = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{jar.toURI().toURL()},  (URLClassLoader) systemCL);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your classloader is probably hanging when it tries to load JDK classes that are referenced from your dynamic classes, because it needs a parent classloader capable of loading JDK classes. You can borrow a functional parent from the current context, i.e.:

```
new URLClassLoader(urls, this.getClass().getClassLoader())
```

Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194698/how-to-load-a-jar-file-at-runtime) if you run into problems after reloading classes that have already been instantiated.

Comment: I had this same issue and tried this same solution already, but it didn't work. The only difference as far as I can tell is that instead of creating a new `URLClassLoader`, I had to create my own class that extends `URLClassLoader` and make a new instance of that instead. Still, I set the parent to `<main_class>.class.getClassLoader()` and set the URLs right and everything seems to work except for the logging, including `System.out.println()`. Can anyone help? Should I make this a separate question?