# Run jar from within a Java application

Tags: java

I am trying to build a simple auto updater for my application. I am currently checking the local application version against my remote version. If there is a newer version I want to start my updater.jar - which basically downloads and replaces the old application.

My problem is that I cannot seem to get the updater.jar to start if there is a new version.

The code I am currently using is:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
try {
    Process proc = runtime.exec("java -jar updater.jar");
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Splash.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
System.exit(0);
```

The application exits but updater.jar is never launched..

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the exception catch block entered (i.e. is there a log message recorded) ?

Answer (score 0):

Your child process is likely exiting when your parent process exits.

When you launch a process you should usually:

1. consume stdout/stderr from the child process. If you *don't* do this your child process can block waiting for its output to be consumed. You should consume in separate threads. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/882795/12960) for more details
2. use `Process.waitFor()` to capture the exit code from the child process

It looks to me like you want to spawn the updater, let it perform a download and then exit your parent process. Anything more complex would likely be platform dependent (e.g. spawning a background process and disowning it)

Comment: Yea im kind of stuck how would code to launch updater.jar look like? Tried bunch of different stuff cant get anything to work

Comment: AFAICT, you can't have child process living after the parent has died in Java. Updating Java software automatically can be a major PITA (even big software products like [IntelliJ IDEA](http://jetbrains.com/idea) had -- if not still having -- a hard time relaunching after successful updates; anyway, I bet they came up with something platform-specific for these purposes).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the path to updater.jar should be specified in the `java -jar` command.

Answer (score 0):

You better use the [URLClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) since jre1.2

see [How to load a jar file at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194698/how-to-load-a-jar-file-at-runtime)