# Java's classloader versus jars-within-jars

Tags: java, jar, classloader

We have an executable JAR file that *sometimes* contains other JAR files.  (The whole thing rests on four other downloaded JARs, riding on the back of a giant deployed turtle in space.)  At runtime, we dynamically load that nested JAR file doing the following:

```
// wearyingly verbose error handling elided

URL nestedURL = the_main_system_classloader.getResource("path/to/nested.jar");
File temp = File.createTempFile (....);
// copy out nestedURL contents into temp, byte for byte

URL tempURL = temp.toURI().toURL();
URLClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{ tempURL });
Class<?> clazz = loader.loadClass("com.example.foo.bar.baz.Thing");
Thing thing = (Thing) clazz.newInstance();
// do stuff with thing
```

This kind of technique has been brought up here before; links include [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194698/how-to-load-a-jar-file-at-runtime).  The code we currently have in place works...

...mostly.  I'd really like to find some way of avoiding the temporary file creation and copying (and eventual cleanup, because as we all know, [deleteOnExit is evil](https://www.google.com/#q=deleteOnExit%20is%20evil)).  The URL obtained right at the start points to a JAR, after all:

```
URL nestedURL = the_main_system_classloader.getResource("path/to/nested.jar");
// nestedURL.toString() at this point is
// "jar:file:/C:/full/path/to/the/executable.jar!/path/to/nested.jar"
URLClassLoader loader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{ nestedURL });
Class<?> clazz = loader.loadClass("com.example.foo.bar.baz.Thing");
```

But loadClass throws a ClassNotFound.

Can the URLClassLoader simply not handle this JAR-within-a-JAR case?  Or do I need to do something to one or more of the paths involved (either the nestedURL or the string passed to loadClass) to make this work?

Comment: I'd probably use this to build a single jar - http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html.

Comment: Have you tried to `addUrl` to your main class loader then load the class normally?

Comment: @PaulGrime Unfortunately, licensing allows us to only redistribute the nested jar files, but not unpack/repack them.

Comment: Hmm, maybe unpacking once at the start, then running the other code with an updated classpath is the best way then. E.g. some code does funky things with calls to `getResource()`, and I'm not sure what the URL should be for a resource in-a-jar-in-another-jar. Do you need to tidy up after, or can you just distribute as a setup jar and unpack and then leave the contents?

Comment: This page lists a lot of resources for nested JAR classloading: http://www.jdotsoft.com/JarClassLoader.php

Comment: That does look handy, although I note that according to that page, they create the same kinds of temporary files which I was hoping to avoid.  If we were creating this project from scratch I would definitely look closer at their product.

Comment: I agree with @PaulGrime, you should consider migrating to Maven Shade. I had a team do this in a big project a while ago, and while it was a bit of work to set up everything right with Maven, once we had it it was very comfortable, even permitting us to obfuscate large parts of third party libs as a side effect. It also forced us to think about and make decisions concerning conflict resolution for overlapping classes from dependent libs. It was a good reason to clean up and get rid of a lot of ambiguity.

Comment: @kriegaex If you'll look two comments later, I already explained why that's not an option for us.  I'm sure Maven is wonderful at a technical level, but the third-party JAR's license forbids all such manipulation.  Thanks anyhow!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the vanilla URLClassloader cannot handle it.

So far this is your answer.

Apart from your solution there are two other possibilities that I am aware of:

1. Create a fat jar (p.ex. using Maven Shade)
2. Create a custom classloader, but this is kind of hard work.