# .jar is not working properly

Tags: java, netbeans, jar

I have two main class in my netbeans project, and in one program I am calling the other Class

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

                NewJFrame k = new NewJFrame();
                k.setVisible(true);
                //close();
```

Both the programs are running fine independently  , and if I run one program then using above button action my new form from the other class is opening, I mean in netbeans everything is working as expected.

But if when I am making jar file and running it , then it runs but the another form is not opening when I click on the button,

Please help me..

Comment: what is the exception/error message ?

Comment: http://wiki.netbeans.org/PackagingADistributableJavaApp

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194698/how-to-load-a-jar-file-at-runtime) might help

Comment: no error message as while clicking on .jar file it is running but while clicking over button the second frame is not opening

Comment: Please post your NewJFrame class; the two lines of code above are not obviously wrong.

Comment: public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

//Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con = null;
   ResultSet rs = null;
   Statement st = null;
  PreparedStatement pst =null;
    public NewJFrame() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        initComponents();
        //setIcon();
        reset.setEnabled(false);
        submit.setEnabled(false);
       //fillCombo();
    }