# How can I specify which OS based Java Library to use?

Tags: java, linux, windows, macos, cross-platform

I have an application which requires the use of 6 different SWT libraries (for each OS of MacOSX 32 and 64 bit, Windows 32 and 64 bit, and Linux 32 and 64 bit).

The application on which I am working I want to be cross-platform and fairly user proof (as in, it should require as little input from the user as possible to get the program to launch).

Is there a way to, based on what case with which I am dealing, tell the application "Hey, use THIS library"?

Something like

```
if (Platform.isMac()){
    if (Platform.is64Bit()) //Use Mac 64 bit Library
    else //Use Mac 32 Bit Library
//Same for Windows
//Same for Linux
```

Is that possible?

### EDIT

I know how to determine the OS. I just need to know how to load a specific jar at run time as a dependent library of another library (say I have a library that requires SWT, I need to be able to tell THAT library WHICH SWT.jar to load based on the OS in which I am currently operating).

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228477/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-operating-system-in-java

Comment: No. I know how to determine the OS. What I need to know is how to specify which JAR to load.

Comment: Oh my bad, now I understand what you want.

Comment: So basically what you want is how to load jars/packages at runtime. Maybe this can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194698/how-to-load-a-jar-file-at-runtime

Comment: I think you could try creating separate child `Classloader`for your platform specific libs depending on your Platform filter condition.

Comment: @sambireddy
I like that idea it sounds like what I need. The next question I'd have to ask is do you have a link to a concise example of how I would go about doing that (not the "determine my architecture part" but the "create separate classloaders" part. If you can give me that in the form of an answer (and I can hammer out the details and make it work) I will accept it.

Comment: @alkis That looks like for what I am looking...

Answer (score 0):

If your java program uses platform specific dependencies you should provide different start scripts for it. Just keep it simple. 
Your scripts can determine the used jdk architecture and configure the proper classpath for it.
I never encountered a java program trying to bootstrap the architectual environment. That's because of the massive efford it would take, except for architectural jni calls which is however not the case with swt.

Comment: Any chance you could provide an example, or a link to what you are talking about?

Comment: Startup scripts for Apache Tomcat for example. You could also try the maven appassembler plugin.